# Linux ELF shared library issue

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, elf

Currently I am working with ELF files and trying to deal with loading SO files. I am trying to "forcibly" link a new (a fake one, without actual calls to the code) SO dependency into executable file. To do that, I modified the .dynstr section contents (created a new section, filled it with the new contents, and resolved all sh_link fileds of Elf64_Shdr entries). Also I modified the .dynamic section (it has more than one null entry, so I modified one) to have DT_NEEDED type with linkage to the needed third-party SO name.

My small test app, being analyzed, appears to be fine (as readelf with -d option, or objdump -p, show). Nevertheless, when trying to run the application, it tells:
`error while loading shared libraries: ��oU: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
Every time running, the name is different. This makes me think some addresses in the ELF loaded are invalid.

I understand that this way of patching is highly error-prone, but I am interested anyway. So, my question is: are there any ELF tools (like gdb or strace), which can debug image loading process (i.e. which can tell one what is wrong before entry point is hit)? Or are there any switches or options, which can help with this situation?

I have tried things like `strace -d`, but it would not tell anything interesting.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, dlopen() is not my case really, as I need to embed SO library reference to the already-compiled ELF file; moreover, the SO library I am working at is going to have at least one function with the ```__attribute__((constructor))``` specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention patching `DT_STRTAB` and `DT_STRSZ`. These tags control how the dynamic loader locates the dynamic string table. The section headers are only used by the link editor, not at run time.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention it, but I have changed values of both these records. BTW, I was thinking about the relative order of sections or DT_* records. Looks like at least the DT_* records order does not matter (as stated in the ELF standard, "These entries’ relative order is significant, though their relation to entries of other types is not").

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I did not manage to find any possibility to deal with sane debugging. My solution came in just because of hard-way raw ELF file hex bytes manual analysis.

My conception in general was right (forgot to mention the DT_STRTAB and DT_STRSZ modification though, thanks to Florian Weimer for reminding of it). The patchelf util (see in the postscriptum below) made me sure I am generally right.

The thing is: when you add a new section to the end, make sure you put data to the PLT right way. To add a new ".dynstr" section, I had to overwrite an auxiliary note segment (Elf**_Phdr::p_type == PT_NOTE) with a new segment, right for the new ".dynstr" section data. Not yet sure if such overwriting might cause some error.

It turned out that I put a raw ELF file ('offline') offset, but had to put this data RVA in the running image (after loading ELF into memory by the system loader, 'online'). Once I fixed it, the ELF started to work properly.

P.S. found a somewhat similar question: [How can I change the filename of a shared library after building a program that depends on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759254/how-can-i-change-the-filename-of-a-shared-library-after-building-a-program-that) (a useful util for the same purpose I need, patchelf, is mentioned there; patchelf is available under Debian via APT, it is a nice tool for the stated purpose)